# Can't compile C++ 17 structured bindings

Tags: c++, c++17, clion

The following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

int main()
{
    auto [i, c, d] = std::make_tuple(1, 'a', 2.3);
    std::cout << "i=" << i << " c=" << c << " d=" << d << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

doesn't get compiled on my computer. I get these error messages:

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'i'
error: expected unqualified-id
```

and some more of the same type.

**I'm using**: Mac OS X 10.11.6 El Capitan, CLion. I **did** choose the C++ 17 option when I created the project and my CMakeList.txt has this line:`set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)`.

clang --version - Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)

What do I need to do to compile this code?

Comment: Are you compiling as C++17 (`-std=c++17` command line option)?

Comment: When compiling with `cmake`-generated Makefiles, you can verify the `-std=c++17` flag with `make VERBOSE=1`. Or export a compilation database and inspect it. The code should compile just fine.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl I'm compiling in CLion, I don't have any command line there. I just choose from the menu Build or Run.

Comment: @lubg could you please what it means in terms of my actions in the IDE? Do you mean that I have to edit CMakeList.txt?

Comment: @alekscooper your editor/ide is still passing options to the compiler when ot runs it. I'm asking what those options *actually* turn out to be.

Comment: My suggestion doesn't have anything to do with an IDE, manually compiling the code via `make VERBOSE=1` requires a terminal (but you should even be able to open one in CLion I guess) and knowing the path to your project build directory. Exporting a compilation data base is indeed done by editing a `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: @lubgr I see, thank you, but I need an IDE-based solution.

Comment: @alekscooper: Please edit your question (the title and example particularly) to make it clear that it is not about C++17 or structured bindings but about using CLion, then.

Comment: I compile it successfully with the latest clion.

Comment: That older version of Xcode does not have complete C++17 support.  (The current version has much better support, but not yet complete, iirc.)

Comment: Recently released Big Sur with its clang 12.0 still has incomplete structured binding support.
for example the bound varaibles can't be captured by lambdas without assigning to some 3rd variable.

Answer (score 2):

As @Eljay said in the comments, older versions of clang did (do) not have complete C++17 support.

I have reproduced this issue w/o CLion.

On a 10.11.6 machine, using "Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)"

```
clang++ -std=c++1z junk.cpp
```

gives the errors that the OP reported. (Note that `-std=c++17` is not a valid option here - that came later)

On a 10.14.2 machine, using "Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)"

```
clang++ -std=c++17 junk.cpp
```

compiles w/o error.

Comment: Unrelated to clang or OS X, but I ran into this issue using CMake. I needed to clear my out of source build directory since I hadn't set the version when it was initially generated! This helped point me in the right direction though, I searched in my Makefile and found no mention of the `-std` flag!